# WordPress Commands out of sync

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I think our WordPress Auto updated, the site started to act slow and we started having these errors on the log.

Erreur de la base de données WordPress Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now pour la requête

```
SELECT  option_value
    FROM  wpih_options
    WHERE  option_name = '_site_transient_wc_pb_db_sync_task_runner_manual_lock'
    LIMIT  1
```

faite par shutdown_action_hook, do_action('shutdown'),
WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_PB_DB_Sync::sync,
get_site_transient, get_site_option, get_network_option,
get_option

Also,
Erreur de la base de données WordPress Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now pour la requête

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM  wpih_options
    WHERE  option_name LIKE
 'wp\\_1\\_wc\\_pb\\_db\\_sync\\_task\\_runner\\_batch\\_%' faite par shutdown_action_hook,
        do_action('shutdown'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters,
        WC_PB_DB_Sync::sync, WC_PB_DB_Sync_Task_Runner->is_queued,
        WP_Background_Process->is_queue_empty
```

Any Suggestions for the best practices to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
INDEX(option_name, option_value)
```